# AutoMapper Custom type converter ITypeConverter and mapping nested objects

Tags: c#, json, matlab, performance, automapper

I am trying to map C# dictionary collection

```cs
IDictionary<string, object>
```

into specific objects used in MATLAB (`MWStructArray` and `MWCellArray`).
The collection holds parsed JSON structure.

For this purpose I use AutoMapper and its `ITypeConverter` implementation, which at the moment looks like:

```cs
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, MWStructArray>().ConvertUsing(new MWStructArrayTypeConverter());
});
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();


public class MWStructArrayTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<IDictionary<string, object>, MWStructArray>
{
    public MWStructArray Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dictionary = context.SourceValue as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var mwStructArray = new MWStructArray(1, 1, dictionary.Keys.ToArray());

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in dictionary)
        {
            mwStructArray[entry.Key, 1] = entry.Value.ToString();
        }

        return mwStructArray;
    }
}
```

My dictionary holds single values like int, string, float etc but it can hold another nested dictionary or List array. I.e.

```cs
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object>>
```

or

```cs
IDictionary<string, List<object>>
```

In case of nested collections I don't know how to recursively map these.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a small sample of the input JSON and the desired output in MATLAB? Are you limited to C# or can you use other languages (maybe the python, mex or java interfaces could help)? If the structure of your data is uniform, perhaps it would be possible to write a parser for your specific schema which would work fast...

Comment: Thanks for the interest. efredin already provided working solution. I tested it and it's perfect. I didn't test it thoroughly yet but few tests I have done so far shows parsing time dropping at least 10 times which is more than satisfying.

Comment: Well, I tested it and calling: context.Mapper.Map<MWStructArray>(entry.Value) throw an exception about not being able to map JObiect into MWArray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map recursively using the context object passed to the convert method.

```
public MWStructArray Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dictionary = context.SourceValue as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var mwStructArray = new MWStructArray(1, 1, dictionary.Keys.ToArray());

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in dictionary)
        {
            if (entry.Value is IDictionary)
            {
                mwStructArray[entry.Key, 1] = context.Mapper.Map<MWStructArray>(entry.Value)
            }
            else
            {
                mwStructArray[entry.Key, 1] = entry.Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        return mwStructArray;
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very, very, *very* much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to edit efredin's answer as it may be fully correct on his system but in my case I had to modify slightly his code and it looks now like that:

```
    public MWStructArray Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dictionary = context.SourceValue as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var mwStructArray = new MWStructArray(1, 1, dictionary.Keys.ToArray());

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in dictionary)
        {
            if (entry.Value is IDictionary)
            {
                mwStructArray[entry.Key, 1] = context.Engine.Map<MWStructArray>(entry.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                mwStructArray[entry.Key, 1] = entry.Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        return mwStructArray;
    }
```